# How to find the records that are waiting to be replicated?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, dmv

I had a look using the replication monitor and it is showing me commands that are awaiting to be replicated:

[image]

My question is - how do I find out what these commands are?

I Have tried [this query by Ben Anderson](https://microsoft.public.sqlserver.replication.narkive.com/zxv6uP7v/sql-2005-replication-querying-msdistribution-status-slow)

```
select @@Servername,a.publication + ':' + s.srvname as [Agent],
v.undelivcmdsindistdb, 
v.delivcmdsindistdb, 
a.id
from distribution.dbo.msdistribution_status v
join distribution.dbo.msdistribution_agents a on v.agent_id = a.id
join master.dbo.sysservers s on a.subscriber_id = s.srvid
where v.undelivcmdsindistdb > 0
```

But the number does not exactly match, although it is definitely a good start,
is there a way I can find more info about these records?

[image]